# Are these sentences grammatical?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, sentence-choice

In a script I'm writing I have a scene where two men enter a floor in a building to search it. Then there are a few other scenes before I return to the two men, who have now just searched the whole floor and are heading for the elevator.

Could you please tell me if the sentences below are all grammatically correct to describe that scene?

1 - Having searched the floor, the men get into the elevator.

2 - After having searched the floor, the men get into the elevator.

3 - Having finished searching the floor, the men get into the elevator.

Answer (score 0):

All three sentences are grammatical. I would think number 2 the most natural, but there is nothing I can point to that is wrong with any of them.